# Transparent/See Through Text in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, layers, transparency, cs5

I would like take this and add an image such that:

[image]

it is only seen behind the white text as if the letters are transparent and the
black
background
also remains, so the image appears behind both, the white text and background and only visible through the text. What is the series of steps to accomplish this if I have the black as a background layer, the "EE"s as a text layer and an image as a separate layer. Or what is the alternative set up, please provide the steps, I am not an advanced user.

EDIT: I do have some experience with the selection tool, but I have no idea how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its Fairly Easy

**Steps:-**

1. Put the Image above your text layer
2. Right click on image layer and select **Create Clipping Mask**

Done!